# Ansible: Including non-managed systems into the configuration

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm writing an Ansible playbook, that sets up systems, where in certain configurations, some systems might be provided by another organization. A very simple example:

Inventory:

- An app server
- A db server

Playbook:
Setup up both servers, and add `application.properties` file to app server with IP, port and user/pass of the db server.

Works so far, but then a requirement comes, that in some deployments the DB server is provided by another organization, so I can't include it in inventory, as the setup step fails, yet I still want to generate the properties file for the app server (with db server info I get from other people).

What would be the least painful solution that would cover both scenarios (my own db server and provided db server), considering there's 6 such server types, not just 2 (so not just 2 different scenarios, there are many permutations of which server is provided for me and which is mine).

Edit: 
To be more specific, the problem I have is that if I use vars when a system is not mine and facts when it is mine, then I have problems writing `application.properties.j2` template, since facts and vars are referenced differently. How would use var in a template, but use a fact if var isn't defined?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have an inventory file per deployment. So an inventory file might look like this:

```
[app]
an-app.server

[db]
a-db.server

[deploymentA:children]
app
db

[deploymentA:vars]
db_ip=foo
dp_port=foo
db_user=foo
db_pass=foo
```

The `deploymentA:vars` you probably would store as `group_vars/deploymentA` but for simplicity I just put it into the inventory.

Now the playbook:

```
- hosts: db
  roles:
    - setup-db-server

- hosts: app
  roles:
    - setup-app-server
```

In a deployment where the db server is not managed by yourself, you simply would not have a db server defined in your inventory. The group `db` would be empty. In that case the first play will simply print "no hosts matched" or something like that and proceed to the next play.

In a deployment where the db server is managed by you, the role `setup-db-server` will be run and you can use the `deploymentA:vars` for configuration.

In your *app* play you have the `deploymentA:vars` no matter if the host is yours or not and can roll out the `application.properties` file.